# Data Type Truncation

Tags: c

I have a basic C question.

Suppose I've declared and initialized a standard 16 bit unsigned integer

```
uint16_t var1 = 0x1234;
```

and then suppose I declared an 8 bit unsigned integer:

```
uint8_t var2;
```

If I were to assign,

```
var2 = var1;
```

would this be a valid statement? And would it simply truncate the more significant bits yielding a result such that:

```
var2 == 0x34
```

evaluates to true?

Comment: Try equating it and try casting it, look at the compiler warnings and the results.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

```
uint16_t var1 = 0x1234;
uint8_t var2;
var2 = var1;
```

Yes, this will truncate `var1` to fit within `var1`'s data type, so `var2` will be equal to 0x34.

Comment: Some compilers (depending on flags) warn about narrowing conversions. But that only for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The compiler would internally interpret this as

```
var2 = (uint8_t)var1;
```

which would result in var2 having the value 0x34.

Comment: Debatable. Remember that `int` need not be more than 16 bits. And there might be additional diagnostics without the casts.

Comment: Look up integer promotion rules. There will be no additional diagnostics. The compiler will convert var1 to int (internally) which in any decent compiler will be a noop in this case.

Comment: Except perhaps for the truncated value warning you mentioned. Mea culpa.

Comment: Anyway, the possibility of extra-diagnostics is a side-show, but if `int` only has 16 bits, casting `0x8000U` or more to `int` is undefined. Of course, the example-value given is safely smaller...

Comment: Hi guys, is it generally better practice to manually include casts so make sure you don't assume the compiler will handle them? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't, but I tend to think about how the compiler is supposed to work. I would never write what I put in my answer. There are rules about expressions that the compiler will follow. In an integer expression, the expression will be interpreted as if all the arguments are promoted to int, unless there is some wider integer or floating point type, in which case sub-expressions will be promoted to the wider type.

Comment: @Teague  - my opinion is yes, but only if you know you're doing something "odd", like truncating a 16-bit unsigned to 8 bits. Otherwise, excessive casts may mask a bug that would otherwise raise a diagnostic. `char *x; char *xx; ... x = (char *) xx;` is very likely a mistake but the cast will suppress a compile-time error.

Comment: @RichardPennington This is not correct. `var2 = var1` internally is `var2 = (uint8_t) var1` without the cast to `int`. The `=` operator is one of the operators (with the cast operator) that does not perform the usual arithmetic conversion on its operands.

Comment: @ouah: I won't dispute that. I started using C before prototypes existed, so I may have missed a change or two in the standard since then. ;-)

Comment: @RichardPennington in that case I suggest to amend your answer (for example by removing the `(int)` cast) otherwise it is misleading